# Attach 2 event handlers to one element to start/stop animation

Tags: javascript, animation, event-handling, boolean

I want to attach 2 event handlers to one `button` to start and stop an animation respectively. I'm trying to use a `boolean` value to test if the animation is already running or not so the right event handler is triggered. i.e. if the animation is not running the `boolean` is false so the run animation event handler will trigger. As soon as I try to add either or both of these handlers the code breaks and the animation won't run. I've not tried using 2 event handlers on an element before and have seen little about it online so I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.

How can I attach these handlers to start and stop the animation ?

```
    <div id='robotCont'></div>    
         <button id='animeBtn'>start/stop animation</button>

div#robotCont {
width:125px;
height:160px;
border:1px solid #22e;
background-image:url("images/robot.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 0px;
}

var robotSwitch = false;
document.getElementById('animeBtn').onclick = function() {
 if(robotSwitch == false) {
  runningRobot();
 } else {
  stopRobot();
}
}

var decrement = 0;
function runningRobot() {
  var robotCont = document.getElementById('robotCont');

  if(decrement < -1900) {
  decrement = 0;
 }
 robotCont.style.backgroundPosition = decrement+ 'px 0px';
 decrement -= 120;  

 timer = setTimeout(runningRobot,100);
 robotSwitch = true;
}


function stopRobot() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
var animate = false
timer;

document.getElementById('animeBtn').onclick = function() {
animate = !animate;

 if(animate) {
    runningRobot();   
 } else {
    stopRobot();
 }
} 

var decrement = 0;
function runningRobot() {
  var robotCont = document.getElementById('robotCont');

  if(decrement < -1900) {
     decrement = 0;
  }
 robotCont.style.backgroundPosition = decrement+ 'px 0px';
 decrement -= 120;  

 timer = setTimeout(runningRobot,100);
```

}

```
function stopRobot() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
}
```